# How can I display a layer group that is published on GeoServer on a webpage?

Tags: web-applications, gis, openlayers, shapefile, geoserver

I have published three shapefiles as a layer group in GeoServer. Now I want to display that layer group in my web application. How can I do it? I am using HTML, CSS, and javascript.

Could you please guide me through the steps to achieve this?

Comment: You can make a wms layer in openlayers or leaflet or several other JavaScript libraries

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a WMS layer published once you created the group and you can use Openlayers javascript library to achieve your goal.

First install the openlayers dependencies on your local environment:
https://openlayers.org/doc/quickstart.html

Now you can go and follow the OpenLayers WMS example:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled.html

Remember to change:

- url: your GeoServer instance URL
- LAYERS: your layers group identifier
- extent: the extent for your layer data and projection